# Appending dataframe in a function

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
```

I need to create a Dataframe outside a function.Like a global dataframe.And make the header of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

global df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Time','Call'])
```

Now I have 2 functions as below.

```
def a():
    #Checking whether the df is available
    if df is None: 
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Time','Call'])
    
    #Appending 
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp1 = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    call_num = 1
    df = df.append({'Time':'timestamp1','Call': call_num}, ignore_index=True)
```

below is the main function.

```
def main():
    a()
    print(1) #Do something
    a()
    
main()
```

Mainly I have a requirement that no values should be passed from `a()` which is in the `main()` function.
How to achieve this.Print two date time information in the data frame.

My current code does not work and giving an error.

Comment: Inside `def a():` declare `global df` outside just do `df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Time','Call'])`

Comment: Could you explain why the global key word come inside the function

Comment: before I go and explain - does it work now?

Comment: Yes Mate,It works

Comment: see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/